# lampp on Centos - unable to stop/start - /opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6

Tags: centos

I've a lampp 5.6.28 installed on Centos.
After a yum update, I was not able to stop/start lampp due to following errors:

```
[root@giunone2 lampp]# ./lampp stop    
egrep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    
egrep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   
egrep: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory     

id: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 11: test: -ne: unary operator expected   
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    
XAMPP: /opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    
apachectl returned 127.   
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
XAMPP: hostname: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   
XAMPP: cat: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]  
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   
kill returned 1.
```

ISSUE SOLUTION
I've found that removing following line everything returned to work OK

**export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5**

Comment: Is there any reason not to use standard apache, php and mysql from CentOS?

Comment: Those alternative Web stacks do not play well with the native OS package manager.  They will give you more problems in the long run

Answer (score 2):

If any version of Redhat or Centos has a 9 in it (cat /etc/redhat-release) this issue will happen.  As stated above, edit /opt/lampp/lampp and comment out export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something which is a little different from the above---but I'm very, very grateful for the posts above. I tried the two fixes above but I got errors using CentOS 6.

XAMPP now starts and runs correctly for me when I commented out this entire section mentioned above in the /opt/lampp/lampp script---from "do we have that new red hat...." down to and including the "fi". COMMENT EVERY LINE and then try starting XAMPP stack.

Answer (score 0):

***at least take a backup/copy the original xampp file before making changes***

My system was `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`
and had the same issue

[image]

I Deleted the entire codeblock from line **441** to **445** to make it work

```
# do we have that new red hat linux 9 with posix native threads?
if test $(osguess) = "rh9"
then
    # for now disable PNTL. if PNTL gets more popular we will support it. - oswald [8apr3]
        export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5
    #echo "XAMPP: DISABLE PNTL..."
fi
```

[image]

Then the XAMPP started normally.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

edit /opt/lampp/lampp

Comment line 436

```
#export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5
```

Uncomment line 437

```
echo "XAMPP: DISABLE PNTL..."
```